# What is the preferred way of notating methods in comments?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, comments, naming, comment-conventions

Sometimes one has to refer to another method when commenting. Here some example in PHP:

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @see B::bar
     */
    public function foo()
    {
        B::bar();
    }
}

class B
{
    public static function bar()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So what if there would be a non-static method `bar` in class `B`?
What is the best way to name other methods in comments?

**Edit**

The PHP manual seems to use `mysqli->affected_rows` as well as `PDO::beginTransaction`. But what it does not is including the parentheses after the method's name. What is pro and con here? I mean it is quite obvious that a method is followed by parentheses, so why no leave 'em out?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `->` operator to reference an instance/object method rather than a class method. PHP.net does that in their manual as well (see [MySQLi class](http://docs.php.net/manual/class.mysqli.php) for example).

Comment: Thx! But even the official PHP documentation isn't consistent. Eg. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php uses `::` :/

Comment: I am shocked, shocked I tell you to hear of inconsistencies within PHP ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
class A {
    // see B::bar()
    public function foo() {
        B::bar();
    }
}
```

My most strongly held opinion concerning my various changes is that letterbox comments are the work of the Devil.  Regarding your static vs. non-static thing, I understand and use `B::bar()` to refer to the function definition for conversational purposes, whether or not `bar()` is static.

The above example is, of course, for illustrative purposes only, because if there were actually a function `A::foo()` that did nothing but call `B::bar()`, I would not include the comment, because if the person reading my code is an idiot, I do not wish to help him.

Comment: 1. Thx! 2. Sorry for asking but I'm no native speaker. What is a "letterbox comment"?

Comment: By letterbox comments I mean the ones where you use /* */ and have that left border of * characters.  The really egregious ones have massive top and bottom borders of asterisks (sometimes even right borders, if you can believe it).  I hate the normal ones, like you have in your example, largely because they remind me of the egregious ones.

Comment: The DocBlock comments are not a personal coding style issue,  but the format that phpDocumentor understands.  It's functional purpose is much like Perl's Pod and a good standard to follow.

Unfortunately, it may offend some programmers' personal coding style, as chaos has noted. However, phpDoc DockBlocks are required in the PEAR and Zend coding style guides & every programmer following a standard has to make a few concessions to their own style, at times.

See: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your example is sufficient. You should refer to B::bar as B::bar(), though.

You might want to consider using the [@uses php-doc tag](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html), which will automatically create a @usedby reference in documentation generated for B::bar(), pointing back to class A.

```
/**
 * @uses B::bar()
 */
```

As far as documentation is concerned, the method being static is not relevant to @uses, @usedby or @see, only @static.  The static notation in the @uses tag simply communicates the scope to look for the bar() method in, not to denote @static.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for phpDocumentor seems to imply that you could use something like

```
class A
{
  /**
   * @see B
   * @see function bar()
   */
  public function foo()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also from the [phpDocumentor manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html):

> @uses is very similar to @see, see the
>   documentation for @see for details on
>   format and structure. The @uses tag
>   differs from @see in two ways. @see is
>   a one-way link, meaning the
>   documentation containing a @see tag
>   contains a link to other
>   documentation. The @uses tag
>   automatically creates a virtual
>   @usedby tag in the other documentation
>   that links to the documentation
>   containing the @uses tag. In other
>   words, it is exactly like @see, except
>   a return link is added automatically.